# Manage dynamic URLs in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I have an issue where almost all URLs parts are optional but the controller is the same. I have a URL with dynamic url-parts which depends from filter when user select some filter parameters URL changes for example:
`/search`, `/search/min-1000`, `/search/max-10000` and so on.

And also I have details URL almost the same as search but has `id` url-part, for example: `/search/{id}/min-1000`, `/search/{id}/min-1000/max-10000`,  `/search/{manufacture-name}/{id}/min-1000/max-10000` and so on.

How can I build such dynamic URLs with angular-router or angular-ui?

Here is example: http://plnkr.co/edit/70Ihz0nqRjiDOKoEJzRI

Comment: You are wanting to pass the constructed url to the url property in ui-router?

Comment: Use /search/:value where value will be replaced by min-1000 or max-1000

Comment: @Sourabh- as you can see url can change it length or url parts

Comment: @tpie I want to handler this urls, and sent to appropriate controller depending of ULR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this with optional parameters:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('details', {
        url: '/cars{make:(?:/[^/]+)?}{model:(?:/[^/]+)?}/{id:[0-9a-fA-F]{24}}{postcode:(?:/postcode\\-\\w+)?}{distance:(?:/\\d+miles)?}{minprice:(?:/min\\-\\d+)?}{maxprice:(?:/max\\-\\d+)?}',
        templateUrl: 'js/app/controllers/details/partials/index.html',
        controller: 'DetailsCtrl'
    })
    .state('search', {
        url: '/cars{postcode:(?:/postcode\\-\\w+)?}{distance:(?:/\\d+miles)?}{minprice:(?:/min\\-\\d+)?}{maxprice:(?:/max\\-\\d+)?}',
        templateUrl: 'js/app/controllers/search/partials/index.html',
        controller: 'SearchCtrl'
    })
    .state('searchMake', {
        url: '/cars{make:(?:/[^/]+)?}{postcode:(?:/postcode\\-\\w+)?}{distance:(?:/\\d+miles)?}{minprice:(?:/min\\-\\d+)?}{maxprice:(?:/max\\-\\d+)?}',
        templateUrl: 'js/app/controllers/search/partials/index.html',
        controller: 'SearchCtrl'
    })
    .state('searchMakeModel', {
        url: '/cars{make:(?:/[^/]+)?}{model:(?:/[^/]+)?}{postcode:(?:/postcode\\-\\w+)?}{distance:(?:/\\d+miles)?}{minprice:(?:/min\\-\\d+)?}{maxprice:(?:/max\\-\\d+)?}',
        templateUrl: 'js/app/controllers/search/partials/index.html',
        controller: 'SearchCtrl'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your params with each defined route in the controller for that route.  Apparently $stateParams creates an object from the url parameters and it gets injected into the route - if you have those params registered with that route.

You can then build a route for each possible construction, registering all the params associated with that route:

/search/:id

/search/:id/:min

/search/:id/:min/:max

/search/:id/:min/:max/:type

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service

Here is an example that is similar to what you are trying to do from egghead.io (I moved it to plnkr to make it a little easier to tinker with:
http://plnkr.co/edit/XhWRMipsfn37bEDwC1sT?p=preview

Each of your routes will need to look something like this:

```
.state('list.item', {
    url: '/:item',
    templateUrl: 'templates/list.item.html',
    controller: function($scope, $stateParams) {
        $scope.item = $stateParams.item;
    }
})
```

They have a video on it here as well:
https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-introduction-ui-router

Comment: I have not register each route as I have 16 URL parts excluding url path with `id`. Aslo url changed dynamically, some url parts may missing and appears.

Comment: Have you considered using a query string instead?  That way you could just use the full string each time and omit or include whatever details in the $stateParams object that you wanted

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#query-parameters